# .removeFromParent() not working

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift2

This is the code that is involved. What is suppose to happen is when the bullet hits and enemy or vice versa they disappear. Not working out at all :(

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Enemy)) {

        CollisionWithBullet(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }
}

func CollisionWithBullet(Enemy: SKSpriteNode, Bullet: SKSpriteNode) {
    Enemy.removeFromParent()
    Bullet.removeFromParent()
}
```

Here is what the game looks like:

[image: The Game]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you're calling it to the class, it doesn't work that way.

You need to have an array of enemies or a single enemy instance and than call

```
removeFromParent()
```

Referencing the specific instances that have been added, not the class itself.

Example:

```
firstBody.removeFromParent()
secondBody.removeFromParent()
```